# Change default line color?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

The default line color in Visio is blue.  How can I change that default?

We have found that you can change each line as you draw but that is a hassle.

I have tried changing the color in the styles menu but it will only hold for one line then flips back to the default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the default properties of Visio's connector tool?](http://superuser.com/questions/226521/how-can-i-change-the-default-properties-of-visios-connector-tool)

Comment: Not really a duplicate since the previous answer talks about changing the master. While this does do the job, there is no longer a need to do this with 2010+

Answer (score 2):

You apply default colours through Themes. You can create a new blank drawing, customise one of the existing themes then save the drawing as a template so that you get access to the customised theme.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you change master-shapes, you have limit: it works only with shapes based on these masters ! not for all shapes in this document.
2. When you change Style, you have limit: it works only with shapes based on style named NoStyle  ! For all shapes in this document, but for other documents you need again change style there.
3. When you change Themes, i think you get limits like as for Styles.